# Unable to use AMDGPU driver in 18.04

Tags: drivers, graphics

I have been trying for several days to get the amdgpu driver running on my HP zbook 15u g3. It is a Skylake i7 with FirePro dedicated switchable graphics. The card in question shows up as Opal XT [Radeon R7 M265/M365X/M465] with 'lshw -c video'. In theory, it should use AMDs open source stack automatically, however it defaults to the older 'radeon' driver. The amdgpu kernel module doesn't even show as installed on a fresh installation of Kubuntu 18.04.

Trying to install an 18.20-based Radeon Enterprise driver from AMDs website (can't use most recent, doesn't work with 4.15 kernel) for 18.04 Gives me errors during install, "Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-43-generic (x86_64)" and "amdgpu dkms failed for running kernel", resutling in a black screen with a mouse cursor, forcing me to run apt-get purge amdgpu* to get a gui back. Installing the latest kernel results in amdgpu showing as installed, but the system still defaults to the radeon driver. Attempting to force the amdgpu driver results in no module being loaded, and the display shows as 'unclaimed' I have confirmed that my series of gpu is definitely supported by the driver, has anyone experienced anything similar?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and for me, the solution required the already-mentioned GRUB (GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT = "quiet splash adeon.si_support=0 radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1 amdgpu.cik_support=1")

...and also deleting /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-amdgpu.conf

Answer (score 0):

Solved with HWE kernel and "radeon.si_support=0 radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1 amdgpu.cik_support=1" added to GRUB